# why display contour so slow in plotly dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am showing a contour plot in plotly dash. From below, I have finished print('Done Updating the contour plot') and return fig in callback function.  But after that it takes really long time to show the contour plot? Any suggestion? Thanks

```
@app.callback(

    Output("padcontour-graph", "figure"),

    [Input("pad-radio-items", "value"), 

     Input("contour-range-slider-items", "value"),  # multiple input

     Input("dropdown-contour-key", "value")

    ],

)

def change_pad_contour(radio_value,range_slider_values,key):

    pad=radio_value

    contour_limit=range_slider_values

    print('limit_min=',contour_limit[0])

    fig=make_one_pad_contour(df_prod_trajectory_dict,key,area,pad,contour_limit,polys)  # 2nd figure is contour

    print('Done Updating the contour plot')

       

    return fig


def make_one_pad_contour(df_prod_trajectory_dict,key,area,pad,contour_limit,polys):
   
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,y=y,mode='markers',marker=dict(color='black',size=3))                    
                     )  
        
    fig.add_trace(go.Contour(
                                z = Z.T, 
                                x = X[:,0], 
                                y = Y[0], 
                                colorscale='Turbo',  
                                contours=dict(
                                        start=z_min,
                                        end=z_max,
                                        size=25,
                                        coloring="heatmap"),
                                zmin=z_min,
                                zmax=z_max,
                                colorbar=dict(
                                        title=key.upper()+colorbar_unit_dict[key],
                                        titleside='right',
                                        titlefont=dict(
                                                size=20)
                                             )
        
                              )
                 )
        
    return fig
```

Comment: Potential causes of slow rendering of plots:
1- Large dataset: It could be that you are generating a plot for a large set of data points. This could slow down your rendering. If this is the case, possibly add a ```dcc.Loading``` component to indicate that the plot is rendering rather than have nothing and wait for it to load.
2- If you have other plots generating along with this one, this will definitely slow down you rendering speed. In which case, you can disassociate the plot rendering callbacks and have certain ones load before trigger the generation of others if this is desirable.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I like the idea if using dcc.Loading to see. Currently I am using callback function to return fig to output of graph region. To use dcc.loading, I think I need to return fig to dcc.loading firstly, then how to transfer this figure from dcc.loading to actual graph region? Thanks

Comment: Hey Roudan, I think the best approach is to wrap the graph region in a loading component by placing it in its children attribute. This way, the graph will be shown in your intended graph region, but it'll show a loading component as it is waiting to be generated. This way, everything is in one place on your dashboard.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. That is a great idea! I will try that!

Comment: Hi Daniel, I made some progress but I still got an error of an object was provided as 'children' instead of a component.  Here is my code:  1. define a graph: 
padcontour_graph=dcc.Graph(id="padcontour-graph", **graph_kwargs),      2: define dcc.loading, padcontour_loading=dcc.Loading( id='loading-pad-contour',children=padcontour_graph) 3. in callback:  @app.callback( Output("loading-pad-contour", "children"),  [Input("pad-radio-items", "value")],  Can you spot some error? Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think the error is from: dcc.Loading( id='loading-pad-contour',children=padcontour_graph) , the padcontour_graph is a object. I need to pass its figure component. How to refer to graph's figure component in dcc.loading()? Thanks

Comment: ok, Daniel, I figured out, in call back the output is till graph's figure instead of dcc.loading's children, so use this:  in callback: @app.callback( Output("padcontour-graph", "figure"), [Input("pad-radio-items", "value")]